# How to use my android smartphone to call a distant modem?

Tags: data-connection, terminal

I have a domotic app using a modem on a RTC line and would like to connect to the modem with my smartphone as I can do with my PC through Hyperterminal. Is there a means to do that, using the phone modem as a data connection dialing the distant number and connectiong in some mode as V32or V32bis? Thank you for any advice.